# Consolidate "sub" Performables in Serenity Screenplay Report

Tags: serenity-bdd

I have created a LoginToAuth0 task to both automate and test my sites login to Auth0 functionality.

My goal is to make the report make more sense and also suppress the login credentials. Is there a way in Serenity to consolidate steps and not be quite so verbose (or is this against the idea of Serenity itself)?

The should method with the groupStepName parameter would be perfect were it to offer an option suppress the reporting of the steps in said group.

```
public final void should(String groupStepName, Consequence... consequences) {...}
```

Is this possible? Also is it possible to do the same for atteptsTo?

Thank you in advance,

Tim

```
public class LoginToAuth0 implements Task {

  @Managed()
  public WebDriver webDriver;

  Actor actor;

  public Auth0Site auth0Site;
  private String email;
  private String password;

  protected LoginToAuth0(String email, String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
  }


  @Override
  public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {

    givenThat(actor).should(eventually(seeThat(auth0Site.isPage())),
        eventually(seeThat(the(Auth0Site.loginContainer()), isCurrentlyVisible())),
        eventually(seeThat(the(Auth0Site.emailField()), isCurrentlyVisible())),
        seeThat(the(Auth0Site.passwordField()), isCurrentlyVisible()),
        seeThat(the(Auth0Site.submitButton()), isCurrentlyVisible()));
    when(actor).attemptsTo(Enter.theValue(email).into(Auth0Site.emailField()), new EnterPassword(),
        Click.on(Auth0Site.submitButton()));

    then(actor).should(eventually(seeThat(auth0Site.isPage(), not(true))));

  }

  public static class Builder {

    private String email = null;
    private String password = null;

    public Builder withCredentials(String email, String password) {
      this.email = email;
      this.password = password;
      return this;
    }

    public LoginToAuth0 build() {
      if (this.email == null || this.password == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException();
      return Tasks.instrumented(LoginToAuth0.class, email, password);
    }

  }

  private class EnterPassword extends SilentPerformable {
    @Override
    public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {
      actor.attemptsTo(Enter.theValue(password).into(Auth0Site.passwordField()));
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would typically group such tasks in a higher level task. You can also use the IsSilent or CanBeSilent interfaces to make tasks not appear in the reports (useful for tasks used in the givens for example)